# Set Map bounds based on multiple marker Lng,Lat

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, mapbox-gl-js

Am using vue and have installed the vue-mapbox component located here:  https://soal.github.io/vue-mapbox/#/quickstart

I have updated the js and css to the latest versions also that gets added to the index.html:

```
<!-- Mapbox GL CSS -->
<link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.51.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Mapbox GL JS -->
<script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.51.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
```

I am trying to utilize this component to set the default view of the map bounds using either `center` or `bounds` or `fitBounds` to a list of Lng,Lat coordinates.  So, basically, how to plug in lng,lat coordinates and have the map default to centering these coordinates inside of the container?

Here's a Component I created, called `Map` in vue to output the mapbox using the component `vue-mapbox` listed above:

```
<template>
  <b-row id="map" class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center my-2">
    <b-col cols="24" id="map-holder" v-bind:class="getMapType">
        <mgl-map
          id="map-obj"
          :accessToken="accessToken"
          :mapStyle.sync="mapStyle"
          :zoom="zoom"
          :center="center"
          container="map-holder"
          :interactive="interactive"
          @load="loadMap" 
          ref="mapbox" />
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</template>

<script>
import { MglMap } from 'vue-mapbox'
export default {
  components: {
    MglMap
  },
  data () {
    return {
      accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic29sb2dob3N0IiwiYSI6ImNqb2htbmpwNjA0aG8zcWxjc3IzOGI1ejcifQ.nGL4NwbJYffJpjOiBL-Zpg',
      mapStyle: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', // options:  basic-v9, streets-v9, bright-v9, light-v9, dark-v9, satellite-v9
      zoom: 9,
      map: {}, // Holds the Map...
      fitBounds: [[-79, 43], [-73, 45]]
    }
  },
  props: {
    interactive: {
      default: true
    },
    resizeMap: {
      default: false
    },
    mapType: {
      default: ''
    },
    center: {
      type: Array,
      default: function () { return [4.899, 52.372] }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getMapType () {
      let classes = 'inner-map'
      if (this.mapType !== '') {
        classes += ' map-' + this.mapType
      }
      return classes
    }
  },
  watch: {
    resizeMap (val) {
      if (val) {
        this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.mapbox.resize())
      }
    },
    fitBounds (val) {
      if (this.fitBounds.length) {
        this.MoveMapCoords()
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadMap () {
      if (this.map === null) {
        this.map = event.map // store the map object in here...
      }
    },
    MoveMapCoords () {
      this.$refs.mapbox.fitBounds(this.fitBounds)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import '../../styles/custom.scss';

  #map {
    #map-obj {
      text-align: justify;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #map-holder {
      &.map-modal {
        #map-obj {
          height: 340px;
        }
      }
      &.map-large {
        #map-obj {
          height: 500px;
        }
      }
    }
    .mapboxgl-map {
      border: 2px solid lightgray;
    }
  }
</style>
```

So, I'm trying to use `fitBounds` method here to get the map to initialize centered over 2 Lng,Lat coordinates here:  `[[-79, 43], [-73, 45]]`

How to do this exactly? Ok, I think I might have an error in my code a bit, so I think the `fitBounds` should look something like this instead:

```
fitBounds: () => {
  return { bounds: [[-79, 43], [-73, 45]] }
}
```

In any case, having the most difficult time setting the initial location of the mapbox to be centered over 2 or more coordinates.  Anyone do this successfully yet?

Ok, so I wound up creating a filter to add space to the bbox like so:

```
Vue.filter('addSpaceToBBoxBounds', function (value) {
  if (value && value.length) {
    var boxArea = []
    for (var b = 0, len = value.length; b < len; b++) {
      boxArea.push(b > 1 ? value[b] + 2 : value[b] - 2)
    }
    return boxArea
  }
  return value
})
```

This looks to be good enough for now. Than just use it like so:

```
let line = turf.lineString(this.markers)
mapOptions['bounds'] = this.$options.filters.addSpaceToBBoxBounds(turf.bbox(line))
return mapOptions
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> setting the initial location of the map to be centered over 2 or
>   more coordinates

You could use [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org) to calculate the bounding box of all point features and initialize the map with this bbox using the `bounds` map option:

http://turfjs.org/docs#bbox

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map

Comment: Thanks, I took your advice and got it working, just need to figure out how to add some padding to the bounds here, cause some of the markers are on the line of the bounds and doesn't have space to show them all.

Comment: There is an [open GL JS issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/7553) regarding adding padding (among other options) to the `bounds` map option. Workaround described there: 
_... set the bounds without additional fitBounds options as a Map option to get it close enough at initialisation, and then immediately call map.fitBounds with the same bounds but with additional options._
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#fitbounds

Comment: `map.fitBounds(bbox, {padding: {top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20}
});`

Comment: or for shorthand `map.fitBounds(bbox, { padding: 20 });`

Comment: I actually winded up creating a filter that added +2 and -2 zoom level to the bounds like so: `Vue.filter('addSpaceToBBoxBounds', function (value) {
  if (value && value.length) {
    var boxArea = []
    for (var b = 0, len = value.length; b < len; b++) {
      boxArea.push(b > 1 ? value[b] + 2 : value[b] - 2)
    }
    return boxArea
  }
  return value
})`

Answer (score 4):

I created a few simple functions to calculate a bounding box which contains the most southwestern and most northeastern corners of the given `[lng, lat]` pairs (markers). You can then use Mapbox GL JS `map.fitBounds(bounds, options?)` function to zoom the map to the set of markers.

Always keep in mind:
**`lng`** (lon): longitude (London = 0, Bern = 7.45, New York = -74)
→ the lower, the more western

**`lat`**: latitude (Equator = 0, Bern = 46.95, Capetown = -33.9)
→ the lower, the more southern

```js
getSWCoordinates(coordinatesCollection) {
  const lowestLng = Math.min(
    ...coordinatesCollection.map((coordinates) => coordinates[0])
  );
  const lowestLat = Math.min(
    ...coordinatesCollection.map((coordinates) => coordinates[1])
  );

  return [lowestLng, lowestLat];
}

getNECoordinates(coordinatesCollection) {
  const highestLng = Math.max(
    ...coordinatesCollection.map((coordinates) => coordinates[0])
  );
  const highestLat = Math.max(
    ...coordinatesCollection.map((coordinates) => coordinates[1])
  );

  return [highestLng, highestLat];
}

calcBoundsFromCoordinates(coordinatesCollection) {
  return [
    getSWCoordinates(coordinatesCollection),
    getNECoordinates(coordinatesCollection),
  ];
}
```

To use the function, you can just call `calcBoundsFromCoordinates` and enter an array containing all your markers coordinates:

```js
calcBoundsFromCoordinates([
  [8.03287, 46.62789],
  [7.53077, 46.63439],
  [7.57724, 46.63914],
  [7.76408, 46.55193],
  [7.74324, 46.7384]
])

// returns [[7.53077, 46.55193], [8.03287, 46.7384]]
```

Overall it might even be easier to use Mapbox' `mapboxgl.LngLatBounds()` function.

As mentioned in the answer from [jscastro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13583598/jscastro) in [Scale MapBox GL map to fit set of markers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62977560/7044424) you can use it like this:

```js
const bounds = mapMarkers.reduce(function (bounds, coord) {
  return bounds.extend(coord);
}, new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(mapMarkers[0], mapMarkers[0]));
```

And then just call

```js
map.fitBounds(bounds, {
 padding: { top: 75, bottom: 30, left: 90, right: 90 },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was going to do the same since react-maps-gl doesn't support `LngLatBounds` out of the box. Appreciate the detailed answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use yet another library for this task, I came up with a simple way to get the bounding box, here is a simplified vue component.

Also be careful when storing your map object on a vue component, you shouldn't make it reactive as it breaks mapboxgl to do so

```js
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            points: [
                {
                    lat: 43.775433,
                    lng: -0.434319
                },
                {
                    lat: 44.775433,
                    lng: 0.564319
                },
                // Etc...
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        boundingBox() {
            if (!Array.isArray(this.points) || !this.points.length) {
                return undefined;
            }

            let w, s, e, n;

            // Calculate the bounding box with a simple min, max of all latitudes and longitudes
            this.points.forEach((point) => {
                if (w === undefined) {
                    n = s = point.lat;
                    w = e = point.lng;
                }

                if (point.lat > n) {
                    n = point.lat;
                } else if (point.lat < s) {
                    s = point.lat;
                }
                if (point.lng > e) {
                    e = point.lng;
                } else if (point.lng < w) {
                    w = point.lng;
                }
            });
            return [
                [w, s],
                [e, n]
            ]
        },
    },
    watch: {
        // Automatically fit to bounding box when it changes
        boundingBox(bb) {
            if (bb !== undefined) {
                const cb = () => {
                    this.$options.map.fitBounds(bb, {padding: 20});
                };
                if (!this.$options.map) {
                    this.$once('map-loaded', cb);
                } else {
                    cb();
                }
            }
        },
        // Watch the points to add the markers
        points: {
            immediate: true, // Run handler on mount (not needed if you fetch the array of points after it's mounted)
            handler(points, prevPoints) {
                // Remove the previous markers
                if (Array.isArray(prevPoints)) {
                    prevPoints.forEach((point) => {
                        point.marker.remove();
                    });
                }

                //Add the new markers
                const cb = () => {
                    points.forEach((point) => {

                        // create a HTML element for each feature
                        const el = document.createElement('div');
                        el.className = 'marker';
                        el.addEventListener('click', () => {
                            // Marker clicked
                        });
                        el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
                            point.hover = true;
                        });
                        el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
                            point.hover = false;
                        });

                        // make a marker for each point and add to the map
                        point.marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
                            .setLngLat([point.lng, point.lat])
                            .addTo(this.$options.map);
                    });
                };
                if (!this.$options.map) {
                    this.$once('map-loaded', cb);
                } else {
                    cb();
                }
            }
        }
    },
    map: null, // This is important to store the map without reactivity
    methods: {
        mapLoaded(map) {
            this.$options.map = map;
            this.$emit('map-loaded');
        },
    },
}
```

It should work fine as long as your points aren't in the middle of the pacific juggling between 180° and -180° of longitude, if they are, simply adding a check to invert east and west in the return of the bounding box should do the trick