# Scale MapBox GL map to fit set of markers

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox

Say I have the following code for a mapbox map:

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = '<token>';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9',
    center: [-96, 37.8],
    zoom: 2,
    interactive: true
});

var geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-77.03238901390978, 38.913188059745586]
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": 1,
                "color": "#007cbf",
                "text": "1"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-78.03238901390978, 39.913188059745586]
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": 2,
                "color": "red",
                "text": "2"
            }
        }
    ]
}

map.on('style.load', function (e) {
    map.addSource('markers', {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": geojson
    });
    geojson.features.forEach(function(marker){
        map.addLayer({
            "id": String(marker.properties.id)+'-circle',
            "source": "markers",
            "type": "circle",
            "paint": {
                "circle-radius": 20,
                "circle-color": marker.properties.color,
                "circle-opacity": 0.8,
                "circle-stroke-width": 0,
            },
            "filter": ["==", "id", marker.properties.id],
        });
        map.addLayer({
            "id": String(marker.properties.id)+'-text',
            "source": "markers",
            "type": "symbol",
            "layout": {
                'text-field': marker.properties.text,
                'text-size': 20
            },
            "filter": ["==", "id", marker.properties.id]
        })
    });
});
```

How would I scale the map to fit a set of points on a map? I can't find any solutions for mapboxgl. Also, I'm not 100% sure that I should be creating a separate layer for each marker, but I couldn't find a way to put all the makers into one layer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `map.fitBounds` that will create a bounding box to adapt map view to a list of coordinates.

```
map.fitBounds([
  [-77.03238901390978, 38.913188059745586],
  [-78.03238901390978, 39.913188059745586]
]);
```

But if you could have a bunch of points in a source as it seems based in your code, then you need to first push all the coordinates of each marker to an array, and then use `coordinates.reduce`

```
var coordinates = coords;

var bounds = coordinates.reduce(function(bounds, coord) {
  return bounds.extend(coord);
}, new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(coordinates[0], coordinates[0]));

map.fitBounds(bounds, {
  padding: 20
});
```

I have created a fiddle for you with this solution, [how to fit mapbox bounds to a list of coords](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/vjkt7wyx/26/), it works your using your own code and coords.
[image]
[image]

Regarding the creation of a layer for each marker, definitely you should try to avoid that practice and create a single layer only to host all the markers.

Comment: Thanks. You said to not create a layer for each marker. I kind of felt this way too, but I couldn't find any way to create my markers on a single layer. Could you possibly tell me how/direct me to documentation?

Comment: Nice it was helpful! You have here an article with  the creation of a circles layer with thousands of points in one single layer https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-circle-colors/

Answer (score 1):

To use Mapbox GL JS `map.fitBounds(bounds, options?)` you can also use an array of `[lng, lat]` pairs which represent the most southwestern and most northeastern corners of the specified geographical bounds.

Always keep in mind:
**`lng`** (lon): longitude (London = 0, Bern = 7.45, New York = -74)
→ the lower, the more western

**`lat`**: latitude (Equator = 0, Bern = 46.95, Capetown = -33.9)
→ the lower, the more southern

To calculate these I created the following functions to get the most southwestern and most northeastern corners of a collection of coordinates and merge them into an array:

```js
getSWCoordinates(coordinatesCollection) {
  const lowestLng = Math.min(
    ...coordinatesCollection.map((coordinates) => coordinates[0])
  );
  const lowestLat = Math.min(
    ...coordinatesCollection.map((coordinates) => coordinates[1])
  );

  return [lowestLng, lowestLat];
}

getNECoordinates(coordinatesCollection) {
  const highestLng = Math.max(
    ...coordinatesCollection.map((coordinates) => coordinates[0])
  );
  const highestLat = Math.max(
    ...coordinatesCollection.map((coordinates) => coordinates[1])
  );

  return [highestLng, highestLat];
}

calcBoundsFromCoordinates(coordinatesCollection) {
  return [
    getSWCoordinates(coordinatesCollection),
    getNECoordinates(coordinatesCollection),
  ];
}
```

To use the function, you can just call `calcBoundsFromCoordinates` and enter an array containing all your markers coordinates:

```js
calcBoundsFromCoordinates([
  [8.03287, 46.62789],
  [7.53077, 46.63439],
  [7.57724, 46.63914],
  [7.76408, 46.55193],
  [7.74324, 46.7384]
])

// returns [[7.53077, 46.55193], [8.03287, 46.7384]]
```